# Template Matrix with Column number equal

Tags: c++, templates

I'm have a homework that tell us to create a template for a matrix where the column number of the matrix1 is equal to the row number of the column 2

I tried that:

```
 #define TEMPLATEMATRIXCR template<class T, int , int > 
 TEMPLATEMATRIXCR Matrix<T, R> operator* (Matrix<T, int, R> a, Matrix<T, R, int> b);
```

It dont work, for example

Matrix [10][30]
Matrix [20][10]
So I need the matrix with [20][30]; //sorry if my logic is messed.
It tells me that the E is not defined.

In the first moment I did

```
TEMPLATEMATRIX Matrix<T, C, R> operator* (Matrix<T, C, R> a, Matrix<T,R, C> b);
```

But it's not what he wants, so now I can't just fix 2 numbers and make the others "free"

How can I do that using templates?

Comment: Just fyi: don't use the homework tag any more. It is obsolete and in the process of being removed.

Comment: why the `#define` for the `template<...>`? It's SOOOOO FUGLY!

Comment: because i'm creating friend methods, a lot of them, so i need to use the template before the declaration, maybe i'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm likely not quite getting what you're asking, but isn't this ultimately what you're trying to do?

```
template<typename T, size_t R1, size_t C1, size_t R2>
Matrix<T, R2, C1> operator *(const Matrix<T, R1, C1>&, const Matrix<T, R2, R1>&);
```

Or are you trying to just make C1 and R2 programatically arbitrary?

Comment: I imagine that i need to get the C1 if C1 is bigger than R1, how can i do that?

Comment: @demonofnight I don't think it matters. matrix [multiplication isn't commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Properties_of_matrix_multiplication), I.e. AB != BA as a rule, so determining the "bigger" isn't really something arbitrary. I think your definition is correct, or again, I'm seriously missing something obvious (wouldn't be the first time).

Comment: And thanks, its what i'm trying to do.. Or, probably i'm missing something, what i thougth is that i just need now to return the C1 if its bigger, if not i  need to return R1 in the Matrix<T, R2, (C1 OR R1)>